# python dictionary get keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I've seen a few people saying

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    print(key)
```

is a more pythonic way than others. Why isn't people using keys() function?

```
for key in dict.keys():
    print(key)
```

Comment: sometimes the `key`'s corresponding `value`(s) are expected to also be used somewhere further in the code, which `dict.items()` returns a list of its (key, value) tuple pairs. However, if you don't need the values, then `dict.keys()` function can be (and often is) used. Which function you use may just depend on your needs/requirements.

Comment: Must have clicked twice :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you only need the keys, then a dict object as an iterable would generate the keys already:

```
for key in dictionary:
    print(key)
```

And if you need the values of the dict, then using the `items` method:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

makes the code more readable than using a key to access the dict value:

```
for key in dictionary:
    print(key, dict[key])
```

The only practical use for the `keys` method is to make `set`-based operations, since the `keys` method returns a set-like view:

```
# use set intersection to obtain common keys between dict1 and dict2
for key in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys():
    print(key)
```